# For what $k$ is $g_k\circ f_k$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, polynomial-rings

Let $\ f_k:\Bbb R[x]_{\le1}\to\Bbb R^3, g_k:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R[x]_{\le1}$ be linear maps such that $f_k(x-1)=\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{0}} \\ 
   k  \\ 
  {1} 
\end{array}} \right),\ f_k(2-x)=\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{k}} \\ 
   0  \\ 
  {-1} 
\end{array}} \right),\ g_k\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{a}} \\ 
   b  \\ 
  {c} 
\end{array}} \right)=(-2a+2kb)x+b-c.$

I'm asked to find the values of $k$ for which $g_k\circ f_k$ is invertible. Now, I think I ought to find its representative matrix $M$ and study its determinant - it shall be a 3x3 matrix. In order to do this, I should find the ones for $g_k$ and $f_k$, say $G$ and $F$ respectively, and then calculate $M=G\cdot F$. Am I right so far?

It seemed to me that $x-1$ and $2-x$ form a basis of $\Bbb R[x]_{\le1}$, so I thought $F=\begin{bmatrix} 0& k \\ k&0 \\ 1&-1  \end{bmatrix}.$

Instead I'm not sure about $g_k$....

Comment: what means $\Bbb R[x]_{\le 1}$?

Comment: Write the representative matrix for $g_k$, just be sure to express it in terms of the basis $\{x-1, 2-x\}$

Comment: @Richard how it can be a ring? If you multiply two polynomials of degree one you get a polynomial of degree two. Maybe you mean the vector space of polynomials of degree at most one.

Comment: @Masacroso Ok sorry, you're right, I wasn't thinking of it. Yes, it's like you say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: observe that $\Bbb R[x]_{\le 1}$ and $\Bbb R^2$ are isomorphic as vector spaces, and because the functions $f_k$ are linear we have that

$$f_k(x-1)+f_k(2-x)=f_k(1)=(k,k,0)\\ 2f_k(x-1)+f_k(2-x)=f_k(x)=(k,2k,1)$$

Thus, the matrix that represent the action of $f_k$ over some polynomial $sx+r\in\Bbb R[x]_{\le 1}$ is

$$M(f_k)=\begin{bmatrix}k&k\\k&2k\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

where I had used the previous isomorphism, that is $\Bbb R^2\ni(r,s)\equiv sx+r\in\Bbb R[x]_{\le 1}$ (and the standard basis of $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$). And for $g_k$ you have, using also the standard basis of $\Bbb R^3$ and $\Bbb R^2$ that

$$M(g_k)=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&-1\\-2&2k&0\end{bmatrix}$$

That is $M(g_k)(a,b,c)^T=(b-c,-2a+2kb)\equiv (-2a+2kb)x+b-c$.

And you want to find $k$ such that $\det[M(g_k)M(f_k)]\neq 0$. You only need to multiply the two matrices and find it determinant to see what values of $k$ make it different from zero.

Comment: +1. Ok, I'm fine with $M(g_k)$... about $M(f_k)$, why does it have to be the basis $\{x,1\}$? I checked that any polynomial of degree at most one can be written as $ax+b=(2a+b)(x-1)+(a+b)(2-x)$, so $\{x-1,2-x\}$ ought to be a system of independent generators... however this would yield a different $M(f_k)$

Comment: That is, it would yield $M(f_k)=F$ as in the OP

Comment: I used the standard basis for $M(f_k)$ to make things easier, that is, using the basis $\{1,x\}$ I can get easily (indeed with zero calculations) the matrix of $g_k$ because I can interpret $g_k$ as $$g_k(a,b,c)\equiv (b-c,-2a+2kb)$$ for the mentioned standard basis. However for the basis $\{x-1,2-x\}$ it is not immediately clear how I can write $g_k$, in any case I would need more calculations.

Comment: Got it! One more thing: even going for your $M(f_k)$, why is $f_k(1)^T$ the first colum and not the second? I mean, the order matters, doesn't it?

Comment: because basis of vector spaces need an order to define a matrix. Suppose I will use the order $\{x,1\}$, assuming that this is an ordered set, then I will had $$M(f_k)=\begin{bmatrix}k&k\\2k&k\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ that is, the column vectors will be swapped. And for $M(g_k)$ I will had $$M(g_k)=\begin{bmatrix}-2&2k&0\\0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$ using this different order on the basis. The point is that vectors are defined by ordered coordinates.

Comment: Right! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If I did my calculations correctly, the representative matrix with respect to the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the basis $\{x-1,2-x\}$ for $\mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq1}$ should be

$$G=\begin{bmatrix} -4& 4k+1&-1 \\ -2&2k+1 &-1\end{bmatrix}$$
The product $GF$ has determinant
$$\det(GF)=4k^2-2k$$
which is non zero for $k\neq 0,1/2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How did you get $G$? Because using the fact that $\Bbb R[x]_{\le1}$ and $\Bbb R^2$ are isomorphic, as of Masacroso's hint, and setting $G\cdot \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c  \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} b-c \\ -2a+2kb  \end{bmatrix}$ I get $G=M(g_k)$ as in Masacroso's answer

Comment: @Richard For example $g_k(1,0,0)=-2x=-4(x-1)-2(2-x)$, so the first column of the matrix shall be given by -4 and -2: these are the coordinates of the image of $(1,0,0)$ with respect to the basis $\{x-1,2-x\}$ for the real vector space $\mathbb{R}[x]_{x\leq1}$. You get the other two columns in the same way

Comment: I see! But then is the method I described above, wrong?

Comment: @Richard either way is right, as soon as one is consistent with the choice for the basis to write the representative matrices

Comment: Got it! Thank you, +1